# Core Data count(for:) is a lot slower than parameter count

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have two entities, `ManagedEvent` and `ManagedEventData`:

```
final class ManagedEvent: NSManagedObject {
  @nonobjc
  class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<ManagedEvent> {
    return NSFetchRequest<ManagedEvent>(entityName: "Event")
  }

  @NSManaged private(set) var name: String
  @NSManaged var data: NSOrderedSet?
}
```

```
final class ManagedEventData: NSManagedObject {
  @nonobjc
  class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<ManagedEventData> {
    return NSFetchRequest<ManagedEventData>(entityName: "EventData")
  }

  @NSManaged private(set) var id: String
  @NSManaged private(set) var createdAt: Date
  @NSManaged private(set) var name: String
  @NSManaged private(set) var parameters: Data
```

The `data` variable of each `ManagedEvent` is a to-many relationship of `ManagedEventData` objects. The `name` variable of `ManagedEvent` is set to the `name` variable of `ManagedEventData`.

Now, I want to count how many `ManagedEventData` objects exist for a certain name. I have found two way of doing this, but one is a lot slower than the other.

The first way is like this:

```
let fetchRequest = ManagedEventData.fetchRequest()
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name == %@", eventName)
return try mainContext.count(for: fetchRequest)
```

For 11k `ManagedEventData` items, this returns in 0.011 seconds.

The other way is to first retrieve the `ManagedEvent` and then get its count by accessing its `data` property:

```
let fetchRequest = ManagedEvent.fetchRequest()
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name == %@", eventName)
return try context.fetch(fetchRequest).first!.data!.count
```

For 11k `ManagedEventData` items, this is way faster and only takes 0.002 seconds.

Why is this and how can I improve the speed of this even further? Does the second way take up a lot more memory because I'm accessing `data`? Is there a better way to model this data?

Comment: You should also research derived attributes, it might be an even faster alternative. See for instance https://www.avanderlee.com/core-data/derived-attributes-optimise-fetch-performance/

Comment: How many `ManagedEvent` there is? If there are less, the fetch will be faster. But it's strange, you the `name` on the child property is the same as the parent? Meaning, all `data.name` is `theManagedEventParent.name`?

Comment: @Larme Probably less than 100. Whereas `ManagedEventData` could be 100k or more. I wanted a way to loop through each stored `name` and then perform counts etc on the data. That was the only way I could think of, to model it as if it was `[String: [String: Any]]` but in core data. Is there a better way?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson That looks like a really good way of doing it, but unfortunately I'm targeting iOS versions lower than iOS 13

Comment: Okay now I've run it again it actually is quicker using `count(for:)`, that's so confusing